# Failed to sync Gradle project after adding google-services Gradle plugin

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-gradle-plugin, google-analytics-api

I'm adding Google Analytics to my application and I'm following the official documentation.

After adding the following line to build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta2'
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' in: C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

My app\build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
...
android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
...
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Removing the classpath line from \build.gradle syncs the project.

Any advise will be appreciated.

Edit: Added target sdk version

Edit2: As per @Tiem Song's answer, it seems that the Google Anayltics library is not working with Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Using just API 23 works.

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

`compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'`

should read:

`compileSdkVersion 23`